# Animating background image relative to mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousemove

So I have an object on a page with a background image and on mousemove it moves the background position relative to the mouse. But the only problem i have is animating the background image to the current position of the mouse when it enters the object.

I am able to animate the background position back to its original position.

**Heres my jQuery**

```
    //MOUSE MOVE, INVERT BACKGROUND POSITION
    jQuery('.homeSlider').mousemove(function(move){
        var moveMouse = (move.pageX * -1 / 15);
        jQuery('.homeSlider .slide').css({
            'background-position-x': moveMouse + 'px'
        });
    });
    //MOUSE LEAVE, ANIMATE BACKGROUND TO START POSITION
    jQuery('.homeSlider').mouseleave(function(){
        jQuery('.homeSlider .slide').animate({
            'background-position-x': '0'
        });
    });
```

*http://jsfiddle.net/TWHh2/*

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
.slide {
    transition: background-position-x 0.5s;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWHh2/1/)

Comment: The downside to this is that it also affects the `mousemove` function, and makes the background image movement no longer smooth and not very responsive.

Comment: @abhitalks It just mades the background-position-x property "transitioned" to 0.5 seconds. That is, changes made to property are updated in a transtioned way.

Comment: @vals: thanks. i used to think it applies only to css events like ":hover" etc. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using CSS transitions as vals suggested, you could also use JS to either set the position or animate it depending on the distance it needs to be moved. If the distance is above a threshold, you can animate it (otherwise the movement is jumpy). Otherwise, set the CSS as you currently are.

Something like this may work:

```
var animating = false;
jQuery('.homeSlider').mousemove(function(move){
    var $slider = jQuery('.homeSlider .slide');
    var moveMouse = (move.pageX * -1 / 3);
    var bgPos = $slider.css('background-position-x');

    if (!animating && Math.abs(moveMouse - parseInt(bgPos)) > 10) {
        animating = true;
        $slider.animate({
            'background-position-x': moveMouse + 'px'
        }, 400);
        setTimeout(function() {
            animating = false;
        }, 400);
    } else if (!animating) {
        $slider.css({
            'background-position-x': moveMouse + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWHh2/2/)**

I would recommend this over the pure CSS solution because that would always apply the animation, which includes small background position changes. If you check the fiddle with the transition, the smooth background effect is no longer very responsive and loses some of its smoothness.

The downside to this is that it becomes poorly-responsive when the mouse moves quickly, similar to the CSS-only solution.

**Alternative**

Combine the JS and CSS transition solutions:

*CSS*

```
.slide.animate {
    transition: background-position-x 0.4s;
}
```

*JS*

```
...
if (!$slider.hasClass('animate') && Math.abs(moveMouse - parseInt(bgPos)) > 10) {
    $slider.addClass('animate');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $slider.removeClass('animate');
    }, 400);
}
...
```

Comment: @TheOne It works well for me when if I don't move the mouse too quickly. The example can also be improved by adding a `mouseenter` event handler, and having your `mousemove` check to see if the background is being animated from the `mouseenter` event. Then you won't need the animate part for the `mousemove` event.